# Modifying the enumerate spacing

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I often type

```
 \itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt
```

after every instance of

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

to adhere to the spacing of the rest of the document. How can I define a new environment that keeps *all* of the enumerate options available but has the default spacing set to what I have written above?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the `enumitem` package and its `\setlist` command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `enumitem` package allows to change `itemsep` and other values in a `\setlist` command.

However, `\parskip` is no list-specific length, it has to be modified within the `before={...}` option, this is a code - hook for `enumerate`.

Please note, that `\setlist[enumerate]{...}` will change the values for all levels of `enumerate`. If a specific level is to be set, use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{...}`, e.g. for the 1st level.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt,before={\parskip=0pt}}

\begin{document}

Foo
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo
\item Stuff
\item Foobar
\item Other Stuff
\end{enumerate}

After enumerate

And a new line

\end{document}
```